# Setting up a Tor Relay on personal computer

Tags: relays

I hope someone can help here. If I set up a TOR relay, would this help in stopping a stalker from monitoring my traffic if for example he hacked into my router? If there is a lot of traffic coming in and out of my network would it be difficult to work out which one is mine? Either way, I would still like to set up a TOR relay but I am also trying to figure out the best way to maintain privacy

Comment: Use Encryption. Are there many people using your Router as there gateway device ? By using Tor , a passive eavesdropper would not be able to make out of your internet activity, unless he is very good at Machine Learning.

Comment: Encryption won't solve the problem here. An eavesdropper still can see what sites the target is visiting. Furthermore with man in the middle attacks it might be possible to break the encryption.

Answer (score 1):

To defeat an attacker who is eavesdropping from your router you don't need to run a relay, you just need to use Tor as a client. They'd only see already encrypted traffic leaving the network.

Running a relay and a client may, under certain circumstances, make it more difficult for a purely passive observer to tell which Tor traffic is yours and which isn't. It wouldn't make it impossible, though.

In your scenario, an active attacker with control of your router, they could simply block inbound traffic to your Tor relay and then the remaining traffic could be determined to be yours alone. I don't think you'll gain privacy by running a Tor relay but using Tor as a client will already give you strong privacy. Your attacker could tell: *That* you use Tor, *When* you use Tor and *How Much* you use Tor.